# Using CASE Statement Within A Derived Column Transformation Expression

Tags: sql, ssis, case, derived

The following is my Data Flow:

```
Ole DB Source > Copy Column > Derived Column >Ole DB Command
```

My `OLE DB` Source has the following SQL command task:

```
SELECT *

FROM Repair R
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vehicle V
ON R.SN = V.SN
AND R.Reg = V.Reg
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product P
ON R.PID = P.PID
```

This yields a column of concern for me named `PartNumber`, which are represented by the following 2 formats:

```
%-%
%-%-%
```

The following are my `Copied Columns`:

```
Input Column = PartNumber
Output Alias = Copy of PartNumber
```

The following are my `Derived Column` expressions:

```
Derived Column Name  Derived Column                  Expression
Name                 Replace 'PartNumber'            LEFT(PartNumber,FINDSTRING(PartNumber,"-",1) - 1)
Copy of Name         Replace 'Copy of PartNumber'  RIGHT([Copy of PartNumber],LEN([Copy of PartNumber]) - FINDSTRING([Copy of PartNumber],"-",1))
```

So My `PartNumber` Column is Replaced with `#########` of type `string` and the `Copy of PartNumber` column is replaced with `####` of type `int`

As I stated earlier `PartNumber` also is in the format of `%-%-%` which raises the following question:

How can I replace `PartNumber` Column with `NULL` if in format of `%-%-%` and take the `PartNumber` and put it in new column named `SubPart` while keeping all the logic within `SSIS` objects?

So in essence I want to do something like the following:

```
PartNumber = CASE
WHEN 'PartNumber' LIKE '%-%-%'
THEN ABC = PartNumber AND PartNumber IS NULL 
END
```

I have tried the case statement in a `Derived Column` expression and is not working.
Would I add the `CASE` statement to the SQL command task in my `OLE DB Source`?

I hope this question is concise for you.

Comment: Part Numbers either look like 4-6 or 7-5-3. If it's in the 4-6 format you want 4 in ColumnA and 6 in ColumnB. If it's in 7-5-3, 7 goes to A, 5 to B and 3 to C.

Comment: Also, save yourself and the person that maintains your code a lot of hassle and name things well. When I inherit columns called "Copy of Copy of Foo", while it's great to have a warning that someone didn't love their code enough to give it a good name, I'd rather not see such things.

Comment: @billinkc When the format is like `# - #` then it is split and the left side of '-' goes in a column and the right side of '-' goes in a different column.  That is working fine.  The problem is that if the format is like `# - # - #` then `PartNumber`  is to put into a column named `SubPart` (I used `ABC` for simplicity) AND make the `PartNumber` column `NULL`..I can't figure out the right protocol to do this to keep my logic within SSIS objects

Comment: @billinkc So if like 4-6 then it is split to 4 and 6, If like 7-8-9 then 7-8-9 is put into a new column while replacing the old column with NULL

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/toddmcdermid/2012/05/22/basic-ssis-equivalents-to-t-sqls-like/

For the solution I made 2 `Derived Column` transformations before my `Copy Column` transformation:

The first `Derived Column` tests to see if `'-'` occurs 2 times, if so, put `PartNumber` in `SubPart derived column`:
Derived Column = `SubPart`, Expression: `FINDSTRING(PartNumber,"-",2) > 0 ? PartNumber : ""`

The second `Derived Column` tests to see if the `SubPart` column `=` `PartNumber` Column, if so then put empty string in `PartNumber` column:

`Derived Column` `Name` Replaces `Name`, Expression:  `SubPart == Name ? "" : Name`

I am perplexed as to why SSIS doesn't have wildcards in there expression library.

Comment: A good rule of thumb with regard to the Expression language in SSIS - if it "scrolls" out of the window, you're probably going to be better served by using a Script Component. Balance that against the other rule of thumb being "Don't reach for the Script Component by default" ;)